# Coderbyte: String Reduction

Tags: javascript, strings

From Coderbyte:

> Have the function StringReduction(str) take the str parameter being
>   passed and return the smallest number you can get through the
>   following reduction method. The method is: Only the letters a, b, and
>   c will be given in str and you must take two different adjacent
>   characters and replace it with the third. For example "ac" can be
>   replaced with "b" but "aa" cannot be replaced with anything. This
>   method is done repeatedly until the string cannot be further reduced,
>   and the length of the resulting string is to be outputted. For
>   example: if str is "cab", "ca" can be reduced to "b" and you get "bb"
>   (you can also reduce it to "cc"). The reduction is done so the output
>   should be 2. If str is "bcab", "bc" reduces to "a", so you have "aab",
>   then "ab" reduces to "c", and the final string "ac" is reduced to "b"
>   so the output should be 1.

Source ( passed all validations ):

```
var replacements = 
{
  "ab" : "c",
  "ac" : "b",
  "bc" : "a",
  "ba" : "c",
  "ca" : "b",
  "cb" : "a"
};

function StringReduction(s) 
{ 
  var original, key;
  while( s != original )
  {
   original = s;
   for( key in replacements )
      s = s.replace( key , replacements[key] );
  }
  return s.length;
}

// keep this function call here 
// to see how to enter arguments in JavaScript scroll down
StringReduction(readline());
```

The funny part of this challenge is that you write against time, so the first version was a terrible, recursive approach. Since then I rewrote it a few times before posting to CR, thinking each time mistakenly that it was perfect, at this point I would like to get your feedback on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few minor notes:

1. > > Have the function StringReduction(str)

   strictly speaking, the parameter name is different:

   > ```
   > function StringReduction(s)
   > ```

   :-)
2. > ```
   > var original, key;
   > ```

   I'd put the variable declarations to separate lines. From *Code Complete 2nd Edition*, p759:

   > With statements on their own lines, the code reads from top to bottom, instead
   >   of top to bottom and left to right. When you’re looking for a specific line of code,
   >   your eye should be able to follow the left margin of the code. It shouldn’t have to
   >   dip into each and every line just because a single line might contain two statements.

   It could prevent some diff/merge conflicts (you modify the first variable, a coworker the second one at the same time).
3. <del>`key` could be declared inside the `while` loop.</del>

   - [JavaScript variables declare outside or inside loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3684923/843804)
   - *Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables*

   As *@konijn* pointed out in his comment, that may [confuse maintainers](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#hoisting). Anyway, extracting it out into a separate function solves the issue (#6).
4. The name `original` could be `lastString` or `lastValue` since it's not the original string, it's the result of the last loop.
5. Indentation is not consistent. Most of the places it's two spaces but the `while` loop is only one space indented, the body of the `for` loop has three spaces.
6. I'd extract out the `for` loop to a `string translate(string, replacements)` function for better readability.

Comment: 3. is interesting, I avoid it due to the hoisting feature in JS which can confuse maintainers (https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#variables) 5. I'm an idiot ;)

Comment: @konijn: 3. Thanks, good point, answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but I have a small update to this program, I believe you do not need the while loop and original because it always executes once or goes in indefinite loop if the string has no replacement combinations.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! How can it work without the `while` loop (or similar construct), given "_If str is `"bcab"`, `"bc"` reduces to `"a"`, so you have `"aab"`, then `"ab"` reduces to `"c"`, and the final string `"ac"` is reduced to `"b"` so the output should be 1._"?